# ListView background changes onFling

Tags: android, listview, android-layout

I've two `ListView`s in a single `LinearLayout`. The background of LinearLayout is a drawable. Everything is working fine, but when I do fling on any of the ListView, the background image disappears and the black background is shown. When fling stops the image gets shown again as a background. I don't want to change the background, Am I doing anything wrong?

The Layout is as following:

```
<LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
    <TextView 
        android:text="Upcoming Trips"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/top_blue_box"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />
    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/upList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="2"           
        />
    <TextView 
        android:text="Past Trips"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_box"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        />
     <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/downList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="2"           
        />
    </LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT:**
The solution is explained [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/01/why-is-my-list-black-android.html) in details, thanks to Robinhood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use

```
listView.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

in java or

```
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
```

inside ListView tag in xml

Answer (score 2):

Apply same color cache hint to listview as your layout color.

**Example:**

```
android:cacheColorHint="light blue"
```

[Cache Color Hint](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/01/why-is-my-list-black-android.html)